# Correct Styling of Listboxes in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm struggling at the moment to style my listbox using XAML as when I apply my style, all the content in my listbox disappears. I'm applying this style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#2a82bb" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And calling it in my list item using:

```
Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}"
```

Does something have to go into the content presenter tag or would I also need to style each list item separately since I'm overriding the default style for the listbox? Any examples would be great as the ones on the MSDN website aren't explained at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListBox` is items control so when you create template instead of `ContentPresenter` use [`ItemsPresenter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemspresenter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<ControlTemplate>
   <Border BorderBrush="#2a82bb" BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
      <ItemsPresenter/>
   </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: When styling a ListBoxItem would I need the ItemsPresenter to be inside of that control template as well?

Comment: When you create `ControlTemplate` for `ItemsControl`, for example `ListBox`, you use `ItemsPresenter` to say where items should be rendered and when for `ContentControl` you use `ContentPresenter` to say where content part should be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                    <Border BorderBrush="#2a82bb" BorderThickness="1" Background="White"/>                       
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```